# MPC-HC + AC3filter playing too fast with DTS-HD MA

Tags: audio, video, ac3

Video plays too fast, as if fast forward was enabled.

It used to happen with VFR MKV video, and was fixed with View > Render Settings > Presentation > Enable Frame Time Correction.

This week this issue started to happen again, and I blamed VFR and tried the same solution. No luck. I updated it to 1.7.6 and still nothing.

But this time I tried to watch a movie with many audio streams. It started with AC3 and played nice, but when I changed it to DTS-HD MA the same issue happened again. Cause found. I changed many times to make sure: AC3 plays fine,  DTS-HD MA plays fast forward.

I verified that AC3filter plugin is being used to decode audio. IDK if I should blame it or MPC. Any idea if setting to change or plugin to install?

Comment: ok I updated ffdshow from 3507 to 4531 and it's woking now. But my receiver reports Dolby Digital instead of DTS, looks like ffdshow's decoder is converting DTS-HD MA to AC3 :/